# How to add customizable payment buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Exist a way to add payment functionality to a button with my own style created with CSS and HTML? I want my own customizable payment button that combines with the aspect of my website and not use the

[image: funky generic PayPal default button].

Comment: adding a javascript onclick event to a button that redirects to paypal? or just using `<a href=""></a>`

Comment: You need to give an example of what service or functionality the button needs to connect to. Without that, people can't give you a useful solution.